# Shell Scripting

Tags: command-line, scripts

I'm trying to run my .sh file but when I try to execute it it doesn't work.
I did `echo '#!/bin/bash' > cadetkpgm.sh` in order for the .sh file to be executable but when I use `./cadetkpgm.sh` or `bash cadetkpgm.sh` to run the file t it doesn't work... any ideas?

Comment: What's the error message? It probably tells you exactly what the problem is ;-)

Comment: ./cadetkpgm2.sh: line 1: cadetkpgm2.sh: command not found

Comment: that's he error that comes up...

Comment: It looks like the line 1 of `cadetkpgm2.sh` is `cadetkpgm2.sh`. Check what's inside the file using `cat cadetkpgm2.sh`, because I think it's not what you think it is. After you fix the content of the file, `bash cadetkpgm2.sh` will run it. You can make it executable with `chmod u+x cadetkpgm2.sh`.

Comment: Also, the she-bang, '#! /bin/bash' should go at the top

Comment: i placed the shebang on the top by useing the echo '#!/bin/bash' > cadetkpgm.sh

Comment: I am little bit confused. What is your file name `cadetkpgm.sh`or `cadetkpgm2.sh`?

Comment: the second one is

Comment: And what is the purpose of this first one. Pls provide a little bit more detail.

Comment: `echo '#!/bin/bash' > cadetkpgm.sh` would overwrite your file to just contain `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: could you write the contents of your script?

Answer (score 1):

`#!/bin/bash` does not turn your shell script into an executable.

It only makes sure that it will be interpreted by `bash` for which you give the location - once you have made it executable by `chmod u+x SCRIPTNAME`.

Let me explain **again**: `cadetkpgm.sh` is **not** a command, **unless** you have made it executable.

Comment: im required to place that into the .sh file. when I try to run it it gives me this error: ./cadetkpgm2.sh: line 1: cadetkpgm2.sh: command not found.

Comment: and it has to be on your $PATH as well.